# How to automagically check radio button on select of dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've seen a few answers for this already, but none that I have been able to make work. I have the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><strong>With selected</strong><br />&nbsp;</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="select_action" value="delete" id="delete"/><label for="delete"> delete</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="select_action" value="assign_to_room" id="assign_to_room"/> assign to room:</td>
  <td><label for="assign_to_room"> 
  <select name="assign_to_room"></select></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="select_action" value="assign_to_board" id="assign_to_board"/> assign to board:</td>
  <td><label for="assign_to_room"> 
  <select name="assign_to_board"></select></label></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><br /><input type="submit" value="submit"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

In Chrome when I select the dropdown, it automatically selects the corresponding radio button, but in IE it does not. How do I achieve this with cross-browser support? I don't mind using JS if I have to.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an on change event to get a radio button by id then change it's value to selected. Just an idea.